# Spark UDAF with ArrayType as bufferSchema performance issues

Tags: scala, performance, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, user-defined-functions

I'm working on a UDAF that returns an array of elements.

The input for each update is a tuple of index and value.

What the UDAF does is to sum all the values under the same index.

Example:

For input(index,value) : (2,1), (3,1), (2,3)

should return (0,0,4,1,...,0)

The logic works fine, but I have an issue with the **update method**, my implementation only **updates 1 cell for each row**, but the last assignment in that method actually **copies the entire array** - which is redundant and extremely time consuming.

This assignment alone is responsible for **98% of my query execution time**.

My question is, how can I reduce that time? Is it possible to assign 1 value in the buffer array without having to replace the entire buffer?

P.S.: I'm working with Spark 1.6, and I cannot upgrade it anytime soon, so please stick to solution that would work with this version.

```scala
class SumArrayAtIndexUDAF() extends UserDefinedAggregateFunction{

  val bucketSize = 1000

  def inputSchema: StructType =  StructType(StructField("index",LongType) :: StructField("value",LongType) :: Nil)

  def dataType: DataType = ArrayType(LongType)

  def deterministic: Boolean = true

  def bufferSchema: StructType = {
    StructType(
      StructField("buckets", ArrayType(LongType)) :: Nil  
    )
  }

  override def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer): Unit = {
    buffer(0) = new Array[Long](bucketSize)
  }

  override def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row): Unit = {
    val index = input.getLong(0)
    val value = input.getLong(1)

    val arr = buffer.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Long]](0)

    buffer(0) = arr   // TODO THIS TAKES WAYYYYY TOO LONG - it actually copies the entire array for every call to this method (which essentially updates only 1 cell)
  }

    override def merge(buffer1: MutableAggregationBuffer, buffer2: Row): Unit = {
    val arr1 = buffer1.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Long]](0)
    val arr2 = buffer2.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Long]](0)

    for(i <- arr1.indices){
      arr1.update(i, arr1(i) + arr2(i))
    }

    buffer1(0) = arr1
  }

  override def evaluate(buffer: Row): Any = {
    buffer.getAs[mutable.WrappedArray[Long]](0)
  }
}
```

Comment: so far I found [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43725688/spark-udafs-how-to-minimize-eliminate-datatype-conversion-copying-and-boxing-o?rq=1) which might help explain things more.

I'm hoping for a better solution.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**TL;DR** Either don't use UDAF or use primitive types in place of `ArrayType`.

**Without `UserDefinedFunction`**

Both solutions should skip expensive juggling between internal and external representation.

**Using standard aggregates and `pivot`**

This uses standard SQL aggregations. While optimized internally it might be expensive when number of keys and size of the array grow.

Given input:

```
val df = Seq((1, 2, 1), (1, 3, 1), (1, 2, 3)).toDF("id", "index", "value")
```

You can:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{array, coalesce, col, lit}

val nBuckets = 10
@transient val values = array(
  0 until nBuckets map (c => coalesce(col(c.toString), lit(0))): _*
)

df
  .groupBy("id")
  .pivot("index", 0 until nBuckets)
  .sum("value")
  .select($"id", values.alias("values"))
```

```
+---+--------------------+                                                      
| id|              values|
+---+--------------------+
|  1|[0, 0, 4, 1, 0, 0...|
+---+--------------------+
```

**Using  RDD API with `combineByKey` / `aggregateByKey`.**

Plain old `byKey` aggregation with mutable buffer. No bells and whistles but should perform reasonably well with wide range of inputs. If you suspect input to be sparse, you may consider more efficient intermediate representation, like mutable `Map`.

```
rdd
  .aggregateByKey(Array.fill(nBuckets)(0L))(
    { case (acc, (index, value)) => { acc(index) += value; acc }},
    (acc1, acc2) => { for (i <- 0 until nBuckets) acc1(i) += acc2(i); acc1}
  ).toDF
```

```
+---+--------------------+
| _1|                  _2|
+---+--------------------+
|  1|[0, 0, 4, 1, 0, 0...|
+---+--------------------+
```

**Using `UserDefinedFunction` with primitive types**

As far as I understand the internals, performance bottleneck is [`ArrayConverter.toCatalystImpl`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/7fdacbc77bbcf98c2c045a1873e749129769dcc0/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/CatalystTypeConverters.scala#L159-L174).

It look like it is called for each call [`MutableAggregationBuffer.update`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/3ff766f61afbd09dcc7a73eae02e68a39114ce3f/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/execution/aggregate/udaf.scala#L246), and in turn allocates new `GenericArrayData` for each `Row`.

If we redefine `bufferSchema` as:

```
def bufferSchema: StructType = {
  StructType(
    0 to nBuckets map (i => StructField(s"x$i", LongType))
  )
}
```

both `update` and `merge` can be expressed as plain replacements of primitive values in the buffer. Call chain will remain pretty long, but [it won't require copies / conversions](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/7fdacbc77bbcf98c2c045a1873e749129769dcc0/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/CatalystTypeConverters.scala#L324) and crazy allocations. Omitting `null` checks you'll need something similar to

```
val index = input.getLong(0)
buffer.update(index, buffer.getLong(index) + input.getLong(1))
```

and

```
for(i <- 0 to nBuckets){
  buffer1.update(i, buffer1.getLong(i) + buffer2.getLong(i))
}
```

respectively.

Finally `evaluate` should take `Row` and convert it to output `Seq`:

```
 for (i <- 0 to nBuckets)  yield buffer.getLong(i)
```

Please note that in this implementation a possible bottleneck is `merge`. While it shouldn't introduce any new performance problems, with *M* buckets, each call to `merge` is *O(M)*.

With *K* unique keys, and *P* partitions it will be called *M * K* times in the worst case scenario, where each key, occurs at least once on each partition. This effectively increases complicity of the `merge` component to *O(M * N * K)*.

In general there is not much you can do about it. However if you make specific assumptions about the data distribution (data is sparse, key distribution is uniform), you can shortcut things a bit, and shuffle first:

```
df
  .repartition(n, $"key")
  .groupBy($"key")
  .agg(SumArrayAtIndexUDAF($"index", $"value"))
```

If the assumptions are satisfied it should:

- Counterintuitively reduce shuffle size by shuffling sparse pairs, instead of dense array-like `Rows`.
- Aggregate data using updates only (each *O(1)*) possibly touching only as subset of indices.

However if one or both assumptions are not satisfied, you can expect that shuffle size will increase while number of updates will stay the same. At the same time data skews can make things even worse than in `update` - `shuffle` - `merge` scenario.

**Using `Aggregator`** with "strongly" typed `Dataset`:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator
import org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder
import org.apache.spark.sql.{Encoder, Encoders}

class SumArrayAtIndex[I](f: I => (Int, Long))(bucketSize: Int)  extends Aggregator[I, Array[Long], Seq[Long]]
    with Serializable {
  def zero = Array.fill(bucketSize)(0L)
  def reduce(acc: Array[Long], x: I) = {
    val (i, v) = f(x)
    acc(i) += v
    acc
  }

  def merge(acc1: Array[Long], acc2: Array[Long]) = {
    for {
      i <- 0 until bucketSize
    } acc1(i) += acc2(i)
    acc1
  }

  def finish(acc: Array[Long]) = acc.toSeq

  def bufferEncoder: Encoder[Array[Long]] = Encoders.kryo[Array[Long]]
  def outputEncoder: Encoder[Seq[Long]] = ExpressionEncoder()
}
```

which could be used as shown below

```
val ds = Seq((1, (1, 3L)), (1, (2, 5L)), (1, (0, 1L)), (1, (4, 6L))).toDS

ds
  .groupByKey(_._1)
  .agg(new SumArrayAtIndex[(Int, (Int, Long))](_._2)(10).toColumn)
  .show(false)
```

```
+-----+-------------------------------+
|value|SumArrayAtIndex(scala.Tuple2)  |
+-----+-------------------------------+
|1    |[1, 3, 5, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0] |
|2    |[0, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]|
+-----+-------------------------------+
```

**Note**:

See also [SPARK-27296](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-27296) - *User Defined Aggregating Functions (UDAFs) have a major efficiency problem*