# How do I implement a fastutils map in a Spark UDAF?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, fastutil

I'm building a Spark UDAF where I'm storing the intermediate data in a fastutils map. Schema looks like this:

```
def bufferSchema = new StructType().add("my_map_col", MapType(StringType, IntegerType))
```

I initialize with no problem:

```
def initialize(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer) = {
   buffer(0) = new Object2IntOpenHashMap[String]()
}
```

Problem comes when I try to update:

```
def update(buffer: MutableAggregationBuffer, input: Row) = { 
  val myMap = buffer.getAs[Object2IntOpenHashMap[String]](0)
  myMap.put(input.getAs[String](0), 1)
  buffer(0) = myMap
}
```

Getting the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.Map$EmptyMap$ cannot be cast to it.unimi.dsi.fastutil.objects.Object2IntOpenHashMap
```

Any way I can make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any way I can make this work?

Not really. This

```
buffer.getAs[Object2IntOpenHashMap[String]](0)
```

is equivalent to

```
buffer.get(0).asInstanceOf[Object2IntOpenHashMap[String]]]
```

and [the external type for `MapType` is `scala.collection.Map`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.2/sql-programming-guide.html#data-types).

In practice it is a dead-end anyway - `UserDefinedAggregate` functions [make full copy of data on each call](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47293454). You might have a better luck with `Aggregator` (as in the linked question).

Comment: Went with the Aggregator approach - now getting an error "No Encoder found for Object2IntOpenHashMap[String]" from the bufferEncoder. Thoughts?

Comment: Figured it out - was using ExpressionEncoder, which wasn't working. My maps are stored in a case class, so all I had to do was Encoders.kryo[MyCaseClass].