# Should I choose RDD over DataSet/DataFrame if I intend to perform a lot of aggregations by key?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataset, rdd, user-defined-functions

I have a use case where I intend to group by key(s) while aggregating over column(s). I am using Dataset and tried to achieve these operations by using `groupBy` and `agg`. For example take the following scenario

```
case class Result(deptId:String,locations:Seq[String])
case class Department(deptId:String,location:String)

// using spark 2.0.2
// I have a Dataset `ds` of type Department   

+-------+--------------------+
|deptId |      location      |
+-------+--------------------+
|     d1|delhi               |            
|     d1|mumbai              |
|    dp2|calcutta            |
|    dp2|hyderabad           |       
+-------+--------------------+
```

I intended to convert it to

```
// Dataset `result` of type Result

+-------+--------------------+
|deptId |      locations     |
+-------+--------------------+
|     d1|[delhi,mumbai]      |            
|    dp2|[calcutta,hyderabad]|            
+-------+--------------------+
```

For this I searched on stack and found the following:

```
val flatten = udf(
  (xs: Seq[Seq[String]]) => xs.flatten)

val result = ds.groupBy("deptId").
                agg(flatten(collect_list("location")).as("locations")
```

The above seemed pretty neat for me.

1. But before searching for the above, I first searched if Dataset had an inbuilt `reduceByKey` like a RDD does. But couldn't find, so opted for above. But I read this article [grouByKey vs reduceByKey](https://www.edureka.co/community/11996/groupbykey-vs-reducebykey-in-apache-spark) and came to know `reduceByKey` has less shuffles and is more efficient. Which is my first reason to ask the question, should I opt for RDD in my scenario ?
2. The reason I initially went for Dataset was solely enforcement of type,ie. each row being of type `Department`. But as my result has an entirely different schema should I bother with type safety ? So I tried doing `result.as[Result]` but that doesn't seem to do any compile time type check. Another reason I chose Dataset was, I'll pass the result Dataset to some other function, having a structure makes code easy to maintain. Also the case class can be highly nested, I cannot imagine maintaining that nesting in pairRDD while writing reduce/map operations.
3. Another thing I'm unsure of is about using `udf`. I  came across [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33899977/how-to-define-a-custom-aggregation-function-to-sum-a-column-of-vectors), where people said they would prefer changing Dataset to RDD, rather than using udf for complex aggregations/grouby.
4. I also googled around a bit and saw posts/articles where people said Dataset has overhead of type checking, but in higher spark version is better performance wise compared to RDD. Again not sure should I switch back to RDD ?

PS: please forgive, if I used some terms incorrectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer some of you questions:

- `groupBy` + `agg` is not `groupByKey` - [DataFrame / Dataset groupBy behaviour/optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32902982) - in general case. There are specific cases where it might behave like one, this includes `collect_list`.
- `reduceByKey` is not better than `RDD`-style `groupByKey` when `groupByKey`-like logic is required - [Be Smart About groupByKey](https://github.com/awesome-spark/spark-gotchas/blob/master/04_rdd_actions_and_transformations_by_example.md#be-smart-about-groupbykey) - and in fact it is almost always worse.
- There is a important trade-off between static type checking and performance in Spark's `Dataset` - [Spark 2.0 Dataset vs DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40596638)
- [The linked post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33899977) specifically advises against using `UserDefinedAggregateFunction` (not `UserDefinedFunction`) because of excessive copying of data - [Spark UDAF with ArrayType as bufferSchema performance issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47293454)
- You don't even need `UserDefinedFunction` as flattening is not required in your case:

  ```
  val df = Seq[Department]().toDF

  df.groupBy("deptId").agg(collect_list("location").as("locations"))
  ```

  **And this is what you should go for**.

  A statically typed equivalent would be

  ```
  val ds = Seq[Department]().toDS

  ds
    .groupByKey(_.deptId)
    .mapGroups { case (deptId, xs) => Result(deptId, xs.map(_.location).toSeq) }
  ```

  considerably more expensive than the `DataFrame` option.

Comment: Thanks alot. Really appreciate the exhaustive list of linked posts :)